# need help to hide url id while editing a record

Tags: php

i'm displaying list of countries information from database to jquery datatable
with edit and delete options.here while editing i'm getting following url
http://localhost/fad/admin/edit_country.php?id=5

i want to hide id number and my url format should be

http://localhost/fad/admin/edit_country/

any one help me to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use form method as `POST` instead of `GET`

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The php file which processes your data should be like this.

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

For your case use this code.

```
<form id="myform<?php echo $country['COUNTRY_ID'];?>" method="post" action="edit_country.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $country['COUNTRY_ID'];?>"/> 
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('myform<?php echo $country['COUNTRY_ID'];?>').submit();" class="tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Edit">click here</a>
</form>
```

Comment: But both codes are different pages..
following is code:
country.php:
<a href="edit_country.php?id=<?php echo $country['COUNTRY_ID'];?>" class="tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Edit"></a>

edit_country.php:
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$queryCountry = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE COUNTRY_ID='$id'";
$resultCountry=$db->select($queryCountry);

Comment: thank you...but one more help i need how to remove .php also
i want url in this format
http://localhost/fad/admin/edit_country/

Comment: create a folder with name `edit_country` and place `edit_country.php` in that folder and rename it as `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Read about mod_rewrite and try to send params as POST.